# Drawing two boxes on barstate.isnew I get four of them on some calculations - why?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Every `barstate.isnew` the script below

1. clears var boxes array
2. draws two boxes  adding them to that var array.

So, there should never be more than 2 boxes.

However, somehow, every candle, the size of box.all becomes 4 on the second calculation and then goes back to 2.

(The label counts calculations on each bar marking "N" for `barstate.isnew`, "C" for `barstate.isconfirmed` and "R" for `barstate.isrealtime`)

Why do the boxes disappear?

If they disappear because they are non-varip then why does the number of boxes go to 4 on second iteration?

The are only drawn on `barstate.isnew` - does the script run twice in `barstate.isnew` state? The debug label only detects one calculation of `barstate.isnew`

In the video below the script in the upper pane draws and clears boxes within `if barstate.isnew` and the script in the lower pane within `if barstate.isconfirmed' (the script below is 'isnew' version): https://youtu.be/_67dWSXY77E

The 'isnew' script has 4 calculations every bar on 3D chart, and the 1st calc on the next bar happens within one replay step.

The 'isconfirmed' script has only 3 calculations every bar, and the box.all size is not going to 4.

Why?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977

//@version=5
indicator("_STUDY: Disappearing boxes")

i_maxBoxes = input.int(10, "Max boxes to draw")
i_maxDbgLblLength = input.int(100, "Max text length for debug label")

// --- methods --- {
method clearObj(box[] _ar) =>
    for _obj in _ar
        if not na(_obj)
            box.delete(_obj)
    array.clear(_ar)

method unshift(box[] _ar, box _val, int _max_size = 100000) =>
    array.unshift(_ar, _val)
    while array.size(_ar) > _max_size 
        _obj = array.last(_ar)
        if not na(_obj)
            box.delete(_obj)
        array.pop(_ar)
// END OF methods }

var arBoxes = array.new<box>()

// --- debug label --- {
var lb = label.new(bar_index, high, "", color = color.rgb(255, 235, 59, 22)) 
varip cc = 0 
varip s = ""
if barstate.isnew
    cc := 0 
cc +=1
s += str.tostring(bar_index) + ": " + str.tostring(cc) 
      + (barstate.isnew ? "N" : "")
      + (barstate.isconfirmed ? "C" : "") 
      + (barstate.isrealtime ? "R" : "") 
      +"\n"
txtOversize = str.length(s)- i_maxDbgLblLength
if  txtOversize > 0
    s := "\n" + str.substring(s, txtOversize, str.length(s)) 
// END OF debug label }

label.set_xy(lb, bar_index, high)
label.set_text(lb, s)

// if barstate.isconfirmed
if barstate.isnew
    arBoxes.clearObj()
    arBoxes.unshift(box.new(bar_index, high, bar_index +1, hl2, bgcolor = color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 44)), i_maxBoxes)
    arBoxes.unshift(box.new(bar_index, hl2, bar_index +1, low, bgcolor = color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 52)), i_maxBoxes)

// --- DEBUG PRINTS --- 


//plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index",  "", location = location.bottom)
plotchar(false, "--- BAR INDEX ---",  "", location = location.bottom)
plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index",  "", location = location.bottom)

plotchar(arBoxes.size(), "arBoxes.size()",  "", location = location.bottom)

plotchar(array.size(box.all), "box.all size",  "", location = location.bottom)
```